# What is the highest spatial resolution for coronavirus cases?

Tags: data, resolution, data-collection, crowdsourcing

I understand that the [JHU CSSE Dashboard](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6) became the watering hole for public health professionals and data science enthusiasts alike, and it visualizes the spread of novel coronavirus (SARS-CoV-2) infections over countries.

In this phase of the disease, however, a finer gradation of the spread could be highly informative, and I cannot locate any good feed or repository of data for smaller units and locales than countries (or Chinese provinces and US states). Not surprisingly, many countries report data at the regional level, but I am not aware of anyone collecting/collating/scraping it.

Does it call for a crowdsourced entry of national (regional?) reports? Has it not been crowdsourced yet?

Comment: 1:1 for me, I think; but UK aren't doing widespread testing so difficult to prove it. Crowdsourcing app would be a nice idea, if it covers suspected/confirmed, and not so detailed as to identify where I live

Comment: Should have been clearer: I meant to crowdsource the scraping of the myriad data sources that are supposed to have a higher resolution than what JHU CSSE grabbed.